# How to use fetch to get POST data from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, rest, flask, post

I am developing a Tweet Sentiment Analysis website using Flask. I have developed the backend of the website .

Backend Code :

```
from flask import *

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('tweet.html')

@app.route('/result',methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_tweet():
    if request.method=='POST':
        tweet=request.form['tweet']
        result=call_predict_function(tweet) #Returns a dictionary having label and score as keys
        return jsonify(tweet=tweet,label=result["label"],score=result["score"])
    else:    
        return render_template('tweet.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I checked the code using requests and it worked as expected. I tried to fetch in frontend . Even though the result is displayed, the data is not printed in console .

Front End code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
       <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h4>Check Your Tweet</h4>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/result">
            <textarea maxlength="300" name="tweet">
            </textarea>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-dark" onclick="GetResults()">Check</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function GetResults()
        {
            fetch(`${window.origin}/result`,{
                method : "POST"
            }).then(function(response)
            {
                if(response.status!=200)
                {
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                }
                response.json().then(function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }).catch(function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not so good in frontend . Where did I go wrong and How can I fetch the POST data from Python?

Answer (score 2):

First mistakes in the frontend:

- `<head></head>` does not include `<div>` or `<h4>`, it is a section for document headers, ie title, meta information such as charset, description, keywords but also links to styles, for example.
- Furthermore, when we use the form, it is necessary to take over the entire solution of the request via JS and suppress the default behavior (ie take the data from the form and go to the url in the action). Or do not use the submit type button, but the `<button type = "button">`.
- Another thing is, missing data attachment to fetch, you are sending a POST request to the url without data in points.

And a few tips for a better code:

- Putting headers into the fetch, at least say what the content is (`Content-Type`)
- Script tag to mark type - `application / javascript`

Frontend with Form-encoded request and JSON ready request:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check Your Tweet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h4>Check Your Tweet</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <textarea maxlength="300" name="tweet">
            </textarea>
            <br><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn-dark" onclick="GetResults()">Check</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        let tweet = document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='tweet']");

        function GetResults()
        {
            // JSON Request
            let fetchJsonRequest = {
                cache: "no-cache",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: {
                    tweet: tweet.value
                },
            }
            
            // Form-encoded Request, like from Form
            let fetchFormEncodedRequest = {
                cache: "no-cache",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    'tweet': tweet.value,
                }),
            }

            fetch(`${window.origin}/result`, fetchFormEncodedRequest).then(function(response)
            {
                if(response.status!=200)
                {
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                }
                response.json().then(function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }).catch(function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```